# Mongodb: find subdocuments whose fields are in non-canonical order

Tags: mongodb, key, subdocument

As I switch to subdoc equality testing, I want to ensure all of my documents' subdocs field orders are in the canonical ordering which I will be testing. I cannot figure out a good query for checking this.

That is, given these records:

```
{'_id': .., 'doc':{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, ..}
{'_id': .., 'doc':{'a': 11, 'b': 21}, ..}
{'_id': .., 'doc':{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, ..}
...
{'_id': .., 'doc':{'b': 0, 'a': 4}, ..}
```

If I query with `'doc' : {'a': 4, 'b': 0}` I won't find the doc w/ keys in the "wrong" order. I'd like to write a one-time query to find all of these docs, but even with `$where` I don't see how I can check the order of keys (I guess the where could try querying with the canonical order if need be).

Comment: The structure here looks a little ambiguous. Are you referring to a single sub-document or multiple, sub-documents under your 'doc' property? At any rate the sub-document structure here is the real problem. And you should consider re-modelling before resulting executing JavaScript over the collection.

Answer (score 1):

So, I wrote a `$where` which does it. I'm not sure it's the best solution:

```
db.mycollection.find({$where: function() { 
    var keys = Object.keys(this['doc']); 
    var ref = ['a', 'b']; 
    for (var i=0; i < ref.length; i++) { 
        if (keys[i] != ref[i]) return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
    }}, 
    {_id: 1})
```

Obviously this is overkill if my docs really only had the 2 subfields, but that's the pattern.